# How can i auto login?

Tags: flutter, logic, sharedpreferences, provider, state-management

I have been working on the auth logic and I have tried many ways so that I can notify the app listeners and auto login immediately save button is clicked and it hasn't turn out well. What did I do wrong?

Many Thanks.

**main.dart file**

```
home: FutureBuilder(         
        future: userPref.isLoggedIn(),
            builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return SplashScreen();
              }
              return !userPref.isLogin ? AuthScreen() : WelcomeScreen();
            },
          ),
```

**auth_form**

````
///tries to submit data entered
  void _trySubmit() {

    ```
    if(isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      print('name = $_name, filePath = $_pickedImageFilePath');
      //save to shared pref
      UserPref userPref = UserPref();
      userPref.save(_name, _pickedImageFilePath);
    }
  }
````

And Also **user_pref** file

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class UserPref with ChangeNotifier {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  final String nameKey = 'username';
  final String filePathKey = 'filePath';
  final String loginKey = 'isLogin';
  bool _isLogin = false;
  var userData = {
    'username': '',
    'imagepath': '',
  };

  ///save user data
  void save(String name, String filePath) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString(nameKey, name);
    await prefs.setString(filePathKey, filePath);
    await prefs.setBool(loginKey, true);

    notifyListeners();
    print('UserPref: data saved');
  }

  ///check if user already logged in
  Future<void> isLoggedIn() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //is user login data saved
    _isLogin = prefs.getBool(loginKey) ?? false;
  }

  bool get isLogin {
    return _isLogin;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the tags of this question, I presume you are using provider as your state management solution.

`FutureBuilder` is a widget that will only evaluate the future once. If you want to continuously subscribe to a change in value, you have to use a `Consumer`:

```
Consumer<CartModel>(
  builder: (context, cart, child) {
    return Text("Total price: ${cart.totalPrice}");
  },
```

Here is a simple example of how you could listen to value changes using provider:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion made me think more and I got it!

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it!
In the **auth_form** I changed

```
UserPref userPref = UserPref(); userPref.save(_name,_pickedImageFilePath);
```

to

```
 Provider.of<UserPref>(context, listen:false).save(_name,_pickedImageFilePath);
```

The **major** difference was saving the data using a `Provider` widget rather than using `UserPref` class directly to save it